# look for the sum of array

Tags: arrays, c

This code is almost done, the only problem is when I try to run it the correct sum is not displayed.
What am I doing wrong here? I think it's correct but I feel like something is missing.

For example:

Enter size: 3

Enter element 1: 2

Enter element 2: 4

Enter element 3: 6

Sum: 12

Average: 4.00

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int size, i;
    float n[1000], avg, sum = 0.0;

    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f",&n[i]);
        sum +=n[i];
    }

    printf("Sum: %d\n",sum);

    avg = sum / size;
    printf("Average: %.2f",avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the output you see for this example?

Comment: For example:

Enter size: 5

Enter element 1: 3
Enter element 2: 2
Enter element 3: 4
Enter element 4: 7

Sum: 16

Average: 4.00

The size and element could be anything, but it has to get the sum and average.
The average from the code provided above displayed the correct answer, but the sum is displaying incorrect answer.

Comment: Sum is float but you are printing as int %d, is this you problem?

Comment: I didn't noticed it.
Yes it was the problem, thank you so much for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

You are using %d for the float format specifier.
Replace:

```
printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
```

with:

```
printf("Sum: %f\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int array[10];
int i , size;
int sum=0;
float average=0;

printf("Enter the size of array");
scanf("%d",&size);
for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
{
scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}
for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
{
sum=sum+array[i];
}
printf("Sum of array element is: %d\n",sum);
average=sum/size;
printf("Average of the element of array: %.2f",average);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).